# neural network parameters not updated inside forloop for mini_batch_gradient descent

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent

I have a neural network on the mnist dataset and am trying to implement mini_batch_gradient descent. I have ran my code using batch gradient descent and although it took forever to finish, it worked. But now I am trying mini_batch gradient descent and for some reason my parameters are not being updated inside my forloop. I'm not sure if there is something wrong with my code but any help would be appreciated.

```
alpha = 0.01
epochs = 10
mini_batch_size = 32
for i in range(epochs):
   mini_batches_x = [x_train[k:k+mini_batch_size] for k in range(0,m,mini_batch_size)]
   mini_batches_y = [y_train_encoded[k:k+mini_batch_size] for k in range(0,m,mini_batch_size)]
   for i in range(len(mini_batches_x)):
     x = mini_batches_x[i].T
     y = mini_batches_y[i].T

     z1, a1, z2, a2 = feed_forward(x,w1,w2,b1,b2)

     dw2, dw1, db2, db1 = backprop(x, y, a2, z2, a1, z1, w1, w2, b1, b2)


     w1 = w1 - alpha*dw1
     w2 = w2 - alpha*dw2
     b1 = b1 - alpha*db1
     b2 = b2 - alpha*db2
```

I have done some debugging and everything else, such as dw1 and dw2 is being updated after the for loop but w1,w2,b1,and b2 do not change at all. I know this is a coding error but just can't figure out why so any explanation and solution will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The problem might be that you are using `i` for both loops. Try changing the inner one to something like `j`.

Comment: @MattCremeens hey thank you for the help, I didn't notice that but that didn't fix what was wrong. The parameters are still not updating and I honestly don't know why. because when I implemented batch gradient descent, everything worked fine.